# Tables are not working in my GitHub Pages site

Tags: github, github-pages

I have a table with three columns and multiple rows. The table is working fine in the repository but if I add the `.md` file to my GitHub Pages site the table remains raw. I know that all the GitHub Pages will be regenerated as `.html` file(s) and all the HTML tags are operating respectively. How can I project the table without HTML tags?

This works:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>var</th>
    <th>let</th>
    <th>const</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Declares a variable, optionally initializing it to a value.
    </td>
    <td>
      Declares a block-scoped, local variable, optionally initializing it to a value.
    </td>
    <td>
      Declares a block-scoped, read-only named constant.
    </td>
  </tr>
  ...
</table>
```

This doesn't:

```
## Variable Declarations
| **var** | **let** | **const** |
|-----|-----|-----|
| Declares a variable, optionally initializing it to a value. | Declares a block-scoped, local variable, optionally initializing it to a value. | Declares a block-scoped, read-only named constant. |
| Variable declared by **`var`** must start with a letter, underscore ( _ ) or dollar sign ($) and can contain alphabetic, numeric, or underscore characters. | Variable declared by **`let`** must start with a letter, underscore ( _ ) or dollar sign ($) and can contain alphabetic, numeric, or underscore characters. | Variable declared by **`const`** must start with a letter, underscore ( _ ) or dollar sign ($) and can contain alphabetic, numeric, or underscore characters. |
```

Here is the [full source](https://github.com/rammurthykota/dev/blob/master/JS/Basics.md), and here is the [rendered output](https://rammurthykota.github.io/dev/JS/Basics.html#variable-declarations) for your reference.

Comment: Generally speaking, please post _source_. Rendered output isn't nearly as useful as seeing the code you're writing (though it can be provided for additional context). Also, please include relevant code _here_, directly in your question as a [mcve]. We shouldn't have to go off-site to understand what you're asking, much less figure out where [the source lives](https://github.com/rammurthykota/dev/blob/master/JS/Basics.md) ourselves.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is almost certainly that you've neglected to put a blank line before your table. Try this instead:

```
## Variable Declarations

| **var** | **let** | **const** |
|-----|-----|-----|
| Declares a variable, optionally initializing it to a value. | Declares a block-scoped, local variable, optionally initializing it to a value. | Declares a block-scoped, read-only named constant. |
| Variable declared by **`var`** must start with a letter, underscore ( _ ) or dollar sign ($) and can contain alphabetic, numeric, or underscore characters. | Variable declared by **`let`** must start with a letter, underscore ( _ ) or dollar sign ($) and can contain alphabetic, numeric, or underscore characters. | Variable declared by **`const`** must start with a letter, underscore ( _ ) or dollar sign ($) and can contain alphabetic, numeric, or underscore characters. |
```